# Word for mac: shortcuts to access Quick Access Toolbar and Ribbon

Tags: ms-office

I am wondering what is the shortcut to access the Quick Access Toolbar and Ribbon in Word for Mac (Office 2019, 16.29.1). In windows you press `Alt`. How do you do it in Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Mac version of Office/PowerPoint doesn't have nearly the number of shortcut keys that the Windows version.

However, On Mac, The option key on many Mac Keyboards are double-labeled Option / Alt. Try Holding down option Key in place of the alternate key.   On a Laptop Machine, you might have to use the Fn (Function key) then the rest of the shortcut.

If the above suggestion doesn't work for you, it's likely that you've run into shortcut keys that just don't work on Mac.

Other Alternavites are:

- [Alt Key Shortcuts on Office for Mac](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/alt-key-shortcuts-on-office-for-mac/121ff361-1174-4164-942a-7603ab5a069e)
- [Shortcut key on Words for Mac](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2008-macword/select-menu-items-from-keyboard-like-altletter-in/7a6ee809-d274-4868-a5d0-2b1dfd7d0ba7)
- [Shortcut key on Excel for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-2016-for-Mac-acf5419e-1f87-444d-962f-4e951a658ccd)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was however looking to have the same sort of shortcuts as you find with Alt. Example: https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2019/08/word2016_2019_ribbon_shortcuts-100808984-orig.jpg

The link that you provide for `Alt Key shortcuts on Office for Mac` does not answer my question: it suggests using Ctrl+F2 to access the menu bar, but I'm specifically looking to control the ribbon and quick access toolbar. I have not found a suitable solution for it yet

Answer (score 1):

I recently built a Mac menubar app that enables alt key shortcuts for Mac Excel. It's called Accelerator Keys, and it's available at https://www.acceleratorkeys.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut for each command in your Quick Access Toolbar using **Tools > Customize Keyboard**. It also lets you create shortcuts for commands not in the Quick Access Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own keyboard shortcuts to: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Just make sure to name them exactly as PowerPoint names them (hover over the shortcut on the Quick Access Toolbar to check the name). See below an example of how I configured some shortcuts.

[image: System Preferences]

[image]